# Error al clonar sitio web Kali linux

Tags: linux

Estoy intentando aprender a clonar un sitio web, en este caso *Facebook*. Ya actualicé todo *Kali* y al clonar un sitio web me aparece esto:

```
set:webattack > Enter the url to clone: http://www.facebook.com
[*] Cloning the website: https://login.facebook.com/login.php
[*] This could take a little bit...

[!] Something went wrong, printing the error: zipimporter() argument 1 must be string, not
 function

root@kali:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

**Posibles soluciones:**

1- Accede al archivo `src/webattack/harvester/harvester.py` con cualquier editor de texto y comenta las siguientes lineas:

```
# detect openssl module
#try:
# from OpenSSL import SSL
# handle import error that openssl is not there
# except ImportError:
# print("Python OpenSSL wasn't detected, note that SSL compatibility is now turned off")
```

2- Accede al archivo `/etc/setoolkit/set.config` con cualquier editor de texto y modifica la linea 95 cambiando `APACHE_SERVER=OFF` por `APACHE_SERVER=ON`

Comment: Gracias, ecién acabo de hacerlo, pero me sigue enviando el mismo error :/

Comment: Actualizado, prueba de nuevo.